# WinAPI C - RunAsUser from REDMON_USER and REDMON_SESSIONID

Tags: c, winapi, runas, redmon

I installed a PostScript printer driver and have setup REDMON (redmonnt.dll) for redirecting postscript output to my program.  In my rather simple c program I capture the data from STDIN and I am able to successfully save it into a .ps file.  The file looks OK.

However, I want to start gsview.exe for viewing the file.  If I call ShellExecute it fails in Windows 7 because of permission issues.  It seems that my program is called under a different user account (LOCAL SERVICE).  So I am looking for a way to run gsview.exe under a specific username (the user who initiated the print job) which is available to the program in a variable called REDMON_USER along with the SESSIONID as well.

**Q:** What are the minimum WinAPI calls required to start a program given a username and a sessionid?

Any code examples in C/C++, .NET would be very helpful.

EDIT: What I am trying accomplish is something very similar to redrunee (from redmonee).  I don't want to use redrunee because it opens about a console window for a brief moment.

Note:
1) The program is called by the printer service as [LOCAL SERVICE] account.
2) The first parameter Username (REDMON_USER), in effect, points to the user currently looking at the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Also look at `CreateProcessWithLogonW` and `CreateProcess`.

They are linked from the CreateProcessAsUser

**EDIT** In reply to comments by OP.

Follow advice from this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/31bfa13d-982b-4b1a-bff3-2761ade5214f).

I am copying this here verbatim, in case the original link stops working:

> The same code works for us on Vista as
>   on XP, etc. The service is running as
>   the Local System.
>
> 1. use WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId to get the ID of the current active
>      Windows session at the console (i.e.
>      the machine keyboard and display, as
>      opposed to WTS sessions).
> 2. use WTSQueryUserToken to get the token for that session.
> 3. use DuplicateTokenEx(hToken,MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,NULL,SecurityIdentification,TokenPrimary,
>      &hTokenDup) to duplicate that token.
> 4. use CreateEnvironmentBlock to create an environment that you will be
>      passing to the process.
> 5. use CreateProcessAsUser with the duplicated token and the created
>      environment. Actually, we use
>      CreateProcessAsUserW, since the A
>      version had some sort of bug on some
>      older systems.
> 6. Don't forget to CloseHandle on the various tokens, etc, and to
>      DestroyEnvironmentBlock the
>      environment.

Thank you [efratian](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/en-US/?user=efratian).

PS. Oh joy of Windows programming, did not do it for quite a while.  Now I remember why. The only thing that is close or even worse documented is OpenSSH programming.

Comment: Both CreateProcessWithLogonW and LogonUser needs a password. The printer monitor sends only two parameters to me, username and sessionid  =(

Comment: The REDMON documentation says it is possible to launch using CreateProcessAsUser with just these two parameters sent by the printer service.

So, How do I obtain hToken from just [Username] and [SessionID] so I can pass it to CreateProcessAsUser?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/en/redmon.htm) describes the "Run as User" feature, which seems to be exactly what you want:

> Run as User is intended for launching a GUI program such as GSview locally via RedRun.

Comment: From what I saw last, redrun.exe uses CreateProcess() in its source code.  Plus, an annoying console window opens up for about 1-3 seconds.

Comment: I also saw redrunee.exe which also has the console window popup issue.  So I decided to write my own redrun.